# How to split a string with delimiter in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string

```
1b00bd515bf8cbc5a86f3b714361fab6
```

and I want to break it down like this:

```
1b00bd51-5bf8cbc5-a86f3b71-4361fab6
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: How are you deciding the break point?

Comment: So...splitting a string every 8 characters?

Comment: This looks like a GUID identifier, and you are trying to get the GUID with dashes. Isn't there a function in PHP to automatically format the string with or without dashes?

Comment: Sorry, your dashes are not inplace for a valid Guid :) My apoligies.

Comment: May be some string function will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use chunk_split function split a string into smaller chunks

below:

```
$str = "1b00bd515bf8cbc5a86f3b714361fab6";

$str = trim(chunk_split(str_replace('-','',$str), 8, '-'), '-');
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: use str_replace('-','') to replace - before after use chunk_split

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chunk_split ()` method to split a string based on fixed length. [link](https://www.php.net/chunk_split)

The  solution should look like this

```
$newstr = chunk_split($string,8,"-");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function split($str, $num, $cr)
{
    return trim(chunk_split($str, $num, $cr), $cr);
}
$str = "1b00bd515bf8cbc5a86f3b714361fab6";
echo split($str, 8, '+');
```

Output:

```
1b00bd51+5bf8cbc5+a86f3b71+4361fab6
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the above but perhaps less code.

```
    $s='1b00bd515bf8cbc5a86f3b714361fab6';
    echo implode( '-', str_split( $s,8 ) );
```